# stopping a script if it was aborted by the user

Tags: bash, sudo, keychain, abort

Please excuse if this is a naive question, I am not a programmer.

I have a script to uninstall a program on OSX and I want it to be good enough to be customer facing.

1. If a user aborts the script using ^C the script for some reason still runs the rest of the script and prints out "uninstall complete" even though it was aborted.

For example if they hit Yes and continue, but then abort on the password prompt using ^C "uninstall commplete" is still printed in the terminal

2. If sudo password is not required, is there a way to hide the "please enter your password" output and only show it if not running sudo already.
3. Delete-generic-password keychain passwords, is there a way to delete all values at once instead of one by one as i currently have it.

#### Uninstall Script

```html
    #!/bin/bash
    red='\e[1;91m'
 NC='\e[0m'
 blue='\e[1;94m'
 cyan='\e[1;96m'

 echo
 printf " Hello ${cyan}$USER${NC}, this will completely remove ${red}Application${NC} from your system"
 echo

 while true
 do
   echo
   printf " Uninstall requires root permission\n Would you like to continue?\n Please enter ${blue}\"Yes\"${NC} or ${red}\"No\"${NC}:"
   read -p " " yn
  case $yn in
   [Yy]* ) osascript -e 'tell application "Application" to quit'
     security delete-generic-password -s "Application Storage" > /dev/null 2>&1
     security delete-generic-password -s "Application Storage" > /dev/null 2>&1 
     security delete-generic-password -s "Application Storage" > /dev/null 2>&1
     rm -rf /Users/$USER/Library/Application
                    printf "Please enter your password\n"
     sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.application.helper.plist /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.application.helper /Library/Application\ Support/Application/ /Applications/Application.app/
     printf "\n ${blue}Uninstall ${blue}Complete \n\n${NC}"; exit;;
   [Nn]* ) printf "\n ${red}Uninstall ${red}Cancelled \n\n${NC}"; exit;;
   * ) echo "Sorry please try again";;
  esac
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put sudo in your script, the user should know when things require sudo and should actually provide it by launching the script with sudo. And if not allow it to fail naturally with insufficient permissions. Also takes care of your other problem.